# Cannot read Danish Characters (Æ, Ø, Å, etc.) with input type file

Tags: javascript, file, input

I am trying to read a CSV file using basic input type file block.

```
readFile (evt) {
    let files = evt.target.files;
    let file = files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"
               onChange={(evt) => {this.readFile(evt);}}/>
```

Original File Content:

[image]

Event Target Result Gives Me : (Text with question marks)

```
This is Question 1 �, � and �","�, � and � This is Answer 1"
This is Question 2,This is Answer 2
"This is ��, � and � Question 3","This ��, � and � is Answer 3"
"This is Question 4 ��, � and �","This is Answer 4 ��, � and �
```

So, is there anyway to read this symbol properly !

Answer (score 2):

Supply the [`encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText#parameters) option to `fileReadAsText` so it can decode the file, or re-save the file with `uft-8` encoding which is more or less the default around the web.

If you are a windows user, the `Save` dialog in Notepad has an `encoding` option where you can set the file encoding to use when saving text.

It is at least technically possible that the file was decoded correctly but the font used by `console.log` doesn't have glyphs for the Danish letters. While unlikely you could try setting the `textContent` property of an HTML element to the text to see if it displays correctly.